# rails 5 api : cannot access to endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get started with rails 5 and building an API to consume it with angular.

I have admin and employee entities, employee create vacationApplication request and the admin accept or reject it.

I start with admin controller coding the first method : index with retrieve all request that are not treated.

here is the controller :

```
class Admin::VacationApplicationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @requests = VacationApplication.where("is_treated = 0").order("created_at ASC")
    render json: @requests, status: :ok
  end

  def acceptRequest

  end

  def rejectRequest

  end


end
```

and here is the route.rb file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :employes
  devise_for :admins

  namespace :admin do
    resources :vacationapplications
    resources :employes
  end


end
```

when start the server and navigate to this uri :

> http://localhost:3000/admin/vacationapplications

i got this error :

> uninitialized constant Admin::VacationapplicationsController

here the rails routes command output :

admin_vacationapplications GET    /admin/vacationapplications(.:format)     admin/vacationapplications#index
                           POST   /admin/vacationapplications(.:format)     admin/vacationapplications#create
 admin_vacationapplication GET    /admin/vacationapplications/:id(.:format) admin/vacationapplications#show
                           PATCH  /admin/vacationapplications/:id(.:format) admin/vacationapplications#update
                           PUT    /admin/vacationapplications/:id(.:format) admin/vacationapplications#update
                           DELETE /admin/vacationapplications/:id(.:format) admin/vacationapplications#destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Rails convention, class names are pascal case (capitalize every new “word” in a class name). This is how you currently have `class Admin:VacationApplicationsController`.

When you refer to this class though elsewhere, such as your route file, you would use snake case to match the separation of words in your class name. Thus your routes for that resource would look like:

`resources :vacation_applications`

Note the underscore between `vacation` and `applications` you’re currently missing.

You haven’t shared your file names, but just to add to the point:
 This match between pascal classnames and snake case is the same for your file names, which would be `vacation_applications_controller.rb` for this resource.

Additionally, since this class is namespaced, it should be in an `admin` folder within your `controllers` folder (if it isn’t already):

**app/controllers/admin/vacation_applications_controller.rb**